# What to do about [order] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag [order](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order), without any tag wiki or excerpt, which sometimes are misused for tag order-statistics, but seems to have other uses, but not many at all.  What to do? Can anybody propose a wiki?

Comment: The tag is unclear, so I'd be more prone to getting rid of it (burinating, merging or making it a synonym of order-stats)

Comment: I agree with @Tim that the tag is unclear and should be eliminated. There are only 21 threads, so I would suggest manually going over them and retagging as appropriate. We have several established alternative tags to choose from (ordered-variables -> ordinal-data, ordered-logit, ordered-probit, ordering->ranking, order-statistics).

Comment: Then I will go through it and retag

Comment: @amoeba, why not make that an official answer?

Comment: @gung Done.$\;$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @Tim that the tag is unclear and should be eliminated. There are only 21 threads, so I would suggest manually going over them and retagging as appropriate. We have several established alternative tags to choose from: [ordered-variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordered-variables)$\to$[ordinal-data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordinal-data), [ordered-logit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordered-logit), [ordered-probit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordered-probit), [ordering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordering)$\to$[ranking](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranking), [order-statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-statistics).

Comment: removed/retagged completed

Comment: Cool! Good job. Maybe mark this answer as accepted to close the issue.